# how to handle Special character in query param value in Rest assured

Tags: java, arrays, json, deserialization, rest-assured

I'm struggling with handling special character in query parameter value while working with Rest Assured.

In url (as given below), I have to pass the value which is separated with pipe symbol '|'. I encoded symbol with value %7C however service call doesn't not give matching response instead returns default response.

http://localhost:8080/api/abc?Id=7325860**%7C**XYZ

Interesting part is same url works fine with any browser rest client or other java based solution.

Answer (score 27):

REST Assured performs URL encoding for query parameters by default. You can easily disable it though:

```
given().urlEncodingEnabled(false).when().get("http://localhost:8080/api/abc?Id=7325860%7CXYZ");
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#url-encoding) for more info.

Comment: This answer save my life today, thank's so much.